# Retrieval of Area Shapes - Here Maps API with V7

Tags: here-api, geocode, here-maps-rest

Is there any way to retrieval of multiple polygons,
Like for e.g, If I should search for **"ABC"** and **"XYZ"** using additionaldata as **'city'**, then I should get both drawn Polygons at the same time.

As per my understanding, in V6.2 we can retrieve only single polygon using searchText and additionaldata.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is not clear to me. Could you share an example of the request?

In general, the response includes a Shape element, which contains the requested outline in WKT (well-known text) format. Depending on whether the requested area is contiguous or not, this will either be a POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON geometry.

For example:

```js
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json
?app_id={{app_id}}
&app_code={{app_code}}
&searchtext=10115+DE
&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,postalCode
```

Sample Response

```js
"Shape": {
"_type": "WKTShapeType",
"Value": "POLYGON ((13.36566 52.53586, 13.36575 52.53579, 13.36582 52.53574, 13.36599 52.53564, ..., 13.36566 52.53586))"
}
```

The response data can be plotted using JavaScript.
This is an example using Geocode version 6: https://developer.here.com/cn/documentation/geocoder/topics/example-reverse-geocoding-shape.html

However, this feature is currently missing in the latest Geocode version 7.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/migration-geocoder/topics-api/geocoding.html